# How can I solve error in loss.backward() of Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I wrote my deep learning model code in Pytorch and PennyLane(quantum machine learning framework).

I checked that the forward process executed well from the result of loss values.

However, I found occured error in `loss.backward()`.

My code is follwing:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(1, 8, 30, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(8, 16, 20, 2)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv1d(16, 32, 10, 2)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout1d()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(160, 64)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 16)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = nn.functional.tanh(self.conv1(x))
        x = nn.functional.tanh(self.conv2(x))
        x = nn.functional.tanh(self.conv3(x))
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = x.view(1, -1)
        x = nn.functional.tanh(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = qlayer(x)
        #print("output of qlayer:", x)

        return x
```

Has anyone experienced where this error is coming from?

```
loss: tensor(-0.6875, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward0>)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 16
     13 train_loader = DataLoader(tr_dataset,batch_size=1,shuffle=True,drop_last=True)
     14 test_loader = DataLoader(te_dataset,batch_size=1,shuffle=False,drop_last=False)
---> 16 loss_list_train = train(train_loader=train_loader, epochs=epochs)
     18 train_loss_df = pd.DataFrame(loss_list_train)
     19 train_loss_df.to_csv('F:/Student/CJG/220916_QC/3_IBM_QLAB/2_result/0_hybrid/1_loss/Train_loss(ROI_'+str(ROI_info)+').csv', index=False, header=None)

Cell In[12], line 16, in train(epochs, train_loader)
     14 print("loss:",loss)
     15 # Backward pass
---> 16 loss.backward()
     17 # Optimize the weights
     18 optimizer.step()

File ~\anaconda3\envs\pennylane\lib\site-packages\torch\_tensor.py:488, in Tensor.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs)
    478 if has_torch_function_unary(self):
    479     return handle_torch_function(
    480         Tensor.backward,
    481         (self,),
   (...)
    486         inputs=inputs,
    487     )
--> 488 torch.autograd.backward(
    489     self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs
    490 )

File ~\anaconda3\envs\pennylane\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py:197, in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables, inputs)
    192     retain_graph = create_graph
    194 # The reason we repeat same the comment below is that
    195 # some Python versions print out the first line of a multi-line function
    196 # calls in the traceback and some print out the last line
--> 197 Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
    198     tensors, grad_tensors_, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs,
    199     allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)

RuntimeError: function ExecuteTapesBackward returned a gradient different than None at position 26, but the corresponding forward input was not a Variable
```

Comment: what is "qlayer(x)" ??, and could you elaborate more on the input. Because the error suggests that Pytorch expects the input in a Variable format.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Thanks for your reply!
'qlayer(x)' is quantum layer in PennyLane(quantum ML framework). I added this layer to apply quantum circuit layer in my model.
"n_layers = 4
weight_shapes = {"params": (8, 1)}
qlayer = qml.qnn.TorchLayer(qnode, weight_shapes)"